# QListView alignment and text wrapping in IconMode

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyside

I am using `QListView` to show a list of files. When I am using its IconMode and file names are too long, I want it to split text in several lines. PySide [documentation](https://srinikom.github.io/pyside-docs/PySide/QtGui/QListView.html#PySide.QtGui.PySide.QtGui.QListView.setWordWrap) tells that `setWordWrap` function would work in other way:

> even if wrapping is enabled, the cell will not be expanded to make room for the text

But that's what I need: break the text and expand item verically.

So, can I use `QListView` to align files in a way it is often done in a file manager? For example, [Thunar](http://docs.xfce.org/xfce/thunar/start):

[image: Text is centered and broken into several lines in Thunar]

This is my current code:

```
import sys
from random import randint

from PySide import QtGui
from PySide import QtCore

app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)

def gen_random_qicon():
    pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap(64, 64)
    pixmap.fill(
        QtGui.QColor(
            randint(0,255), randint(0,255), randint(0,255), 255
        )
    )
    icon = QtGui.QIcon()
    icon.addPixmap(pixmap)
    return(icon)

class Test_model(QtCore.QAbstractListModel):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Test_model, self).__init__(parent)
        self.__items = []

    def appendItem(self, item):
        index = len(self.__items)

        self.beginInsertRows(QtCore.QModelIndex(), index, index)
        self.__items.append(item)
        self.endInsertRows()

    def rowCount(self, parent):
        return len(self.__items)

    def data(self, index, role):
        image = self.__items[index.row()]
        if role == QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole:
            return image['name']
        if role == QtCore.Qt.DecorationRole:
            return gen_random_qicon()
        return None

test_names = ["AB", "UO0E5", "WTRE76", "OSBTTEJ", "M4T2GW4Y55", "LI QM6WJKBC",
              "B4MO4 R6JD6"]
test_model = Test_model()
for tn in test_names:
    test_model.appendItem({"name": tn})

lv = QtGui.QListView()
lv.setFlow(QtGui.QListView.LeftToRight)
lv.setResizeMode(QtGui.QListView.Adjust)
lv.setViewMode(QtGui.QListView.IconMode)

# Grid
lv.setGridSize(QtCore.QSize(64, 64))
lv.setTextElideMode(QtCore.Qt.ElideNone)

lv.setModel(test_model)

lv.resize(250, 200)
lv.show()

sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

When I use `setGridSize` function and set textElideMode as `ElideNone`, I have this result:

[image: QListView with setGridSize and textElideMode as ElideNone]

Otherwise, I see complete names, but I won't have the alignment.

[image: QListView without setGridSize]

Comment: [https://stackoverflow.com/a/69489044/7339351](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69489044/7339351) This answer solves my question.