# How to get item text to wrap using a QListView set to IconMode and model set to QFileSystemModel

Tags: python, pyside2, qlistview

I am using a `QListView` and a `QFileSystemModel` to display the contents of a directory.  I'm trying to emulate the Windows File Explorer, where if the file/folder text is long enough it wraps to display the full name of the object.

As it looks in File Explorer

[image: File Explorer View]

On my view I've tried `setGridSize(QtCore.QSize(80, 80))` to give me enough space, `setWordWrap(True)`, and `setTextElideMode(QtCore.Qt.ElideNone)`

But the text still gets cropped.

[image: QListView Cropped Text]

I've looked into using a `QStyledItemDelegate` in order to wrap the text, but I am unsure how to go about getting the behavior I want.

How can I set the view to show the text wrapping and not cropping any of the text?

Here's the code I've created so far...

```
import sys

from PySide2 import QtCore
from PySide2 import QtWidgets
from shiboken2 import wrapInstance


class TreeViewDialog(QtWidgets.QDialog):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(TreeViewDialog, self).__init__(parent)

        self.setMinimumSize(500, 400)

        self.create_widgets()
        self.create_layout()

    def create_widgets(self):
        root_path = r"C:\Users\Documents\Test"

        self.model = QtWidgets.QFileSystemModel()
        self.model.setRootPath(root_path)

        self.list_view = QtWidgets.QListView()

        self.list_view.setViewMode(QtWidgets.QListView.IconMode)
        self.list_view.setResizeMode(QtWidgets.QListView.Adjust)
        self.list_view.setFlow(QtWidgets.QListView.LeftToRight)
        self.list_view.setMovement(QtWidgets.QListView.Snap)
        self.list_view.setModel(self.model)
        self.list_view.setRootIndex(self.model.index(root_path))
        self.list_view.setGridSize(QtCore.QSize(80, 80))
        self.list_view.setUniformItemSizes(True)
        self.list_view.setWordWrap(True)
        self.list_view.setTextElideMode(QtCore.Qt.ElideNone)

    def create_layout(self):
        main_layout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self)
        main_layout.setContentsMargins(2, 2, 2, 2)
        main_layout.addWidget(self.list_view)



if __name__ == "__main__":

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication.instance()
    if not app:
        app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

    tree_view_dialog = TreeViewDialog()
    tree_view_dialog.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 3):

So I was able to get the behavior I was looking for by implementing a custom `QStyledItemDelegate` and implementing the `paint()` and `sizeHint()` methods and setting `setItemDelegate()` on my `QListView`.

```
delegate = FileNameDelegate(self)
self.list_view.setItemDelegate(delegate)
```

Here's my delegate class.

```
class FileNameDelegate(QtWidgets.QStyledItemDelegate):
    """Delegate to wrap filenames."""

    def paint(self, painter, option, index):
        if not index.isValid():
            return

        painter.save()

        # Selected
        if option.state & QtWidgets.QStyle.State_Selected:
            painter.fillRect(option.rect, option.palette.highlight())

        # Icon
        icon = index.data(QtCore.Qt.DecorationRole)
        
        mode = QtGui.QIcon.Normal
        state = QtGui.QIcon.On if option.state & QtWidgets.QStyle.State_Open else QtGui.QIcon.Off
        icon_rect = QtCore.QRect(option.rect)
        icon_rect.setSize(QtCore.QSize(option.rect.width(), 40))
        icon.paint(painter, icon_rect, alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter | QtCore.Qt.AlignVCenter, mode=mode, state=state)

        # Text
        text = index.data(QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole)
        font = QtWidgets.QApplication.font()
        font_metrics = QtGui.QFontMetrics(font)
        padding = 8
        rect = font_metrics.boundingRect(option.rect.left()+padding/2, option.rect.bottom()-icon_rect.height()+padding/2,
                                         option.rect.width()-padding, option.rect.height()-padding,
                                         QtCore.Qt.AlignHCenter | QtCore.Qt.AlignTop | QtCore.Qt.TextWrapAnywhere,
                                         text)
        color = QtWidgets.QApplication.palette().text().color()
        pen = QtGui.QPen(color)
        painter.setPen(pen)
        painter.setFont(font)
        painter.drawText(rect, QtCore.Qt.AlignLeft | QtCore.Qt.AlignTop | QtCore.Qt.TextWrapAnywhere, text)

        painter.restore()
    
    def sizeHint(self, option, index):
        if not index.isValid():
            return super(FileNameDelegate, self).sizeHint(option, index)
        else:
            text = index.data()
            font = QtWidgets.QApplication.font()
            font_metrics = QtGui.QFontMetrics(font)
            rect = font_metrics.boundingRect(0, 0, option.rect.width(), 0,
                                         QtCore.Qt.AlignLeft | QtCore.Qt.AlignTop | QtCore.Qt.TextWrapAnywhere,
                                         text)
            size = QtCore.QSize(option.rect.width(), option.rect.height()+rect.height())
            return size
```

I now get this when running the code.

[image: Properly wrapping text]

Comment: While using a delegate is certainly the right path, unfortunately it's not sufficient, and your solution has important issues: 1. if a file name longer, the text will overlap any icon that is under it; 2. the wrap happens anywhere, while it should consider spaces (and hypens) as much as possible; 3. the focus rectangle is not properly constructed, so clicking on a lower line won't result in selecting the file; 4. due to the same problem, if the style highlights only the text when the item is selected, the selection rectangle is wrong: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xdFJf.png

Comment: I see what you mean.  I'm only just familiarizing myself with all of the bits you have to implement when doing custom painting, and haven't found a good example.  Looking at the File Explorer as a reference the names get elided after 43 characters it seems.  I will have to calculate the the correct rect for selection as well.

Comment: Achieving this is *not* easy, and should be done with extreme care due to the complex way the view manages item positions and displays all elements (including focus rectangles and selections). I'm going to put a related answer that should address these and other issues as well.

Comment: hi there i am just bumping this to see what the related answer @musicamante was referring to...

Comment: @user3696118 You're perfectly right. Unfortunately, I didn't had the time to finish my own answer back then, and I completely forgot about it in the end. I'll see if I can get it back in the next days (no promises, but I hope to; I suggest you to subscribe the updates by clicking on the "Follow" button of the question).