# Issue with filtering FlowLayout items in PyQt5

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyqt5, maya

I am trying to get a filter feature working for this browser type interface i wrote, but I am facing an issue where when i filter the icon layouts looks all wrong.

Here is what it looks like normally:
[image: looks normal enough]

and here is what it looks like with a filter applied:
[image: as you can see there are weird spacings in between the items now]

I am sure this has something to do with me showing/hiding these widgets, but i don't really know how else to do this without destroying the C++ object each time.

Here is the base code i am working with:

```
import sys, re, os
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
PATTERN = re.compile(r'(\d+)(\.)([0-9a-zA-Z]+$)')
HTML_STRING = '<p align=\"center\">{body}</p>'

class FlowLayout(QtWidgets.QLayout):
    heightChanged = QtCore.pyqtSignal(int)
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(FlowLayout, self).__init__(parent)

        if parent is not None:
            self.setContentsMargins(QtCore.QMargins(0, 0, 0, 0))

        self._item_list = []

    def __del__(self):
        item = self.takeAt(0)
        while item:
            item = self.takeAt(0)

    def addItem(self, item):
        self._item_list.append(item)

    def count(self):
        return len(self._item_list)

    def itemAt(self, index):
        if 0 <= index < len(self._item_list):
            return self._item_list[index]

        return None

    def takeAt(self, index):
        if 0 <= index < len(self._item_list):
            return self._item_list.pop(index)

        return None

    def expandingDirections(self):
        return QtCore.Qt.Orientation(0)

    def hasHeightForWidth(self):
        return True

    def heightForWidth(self, width):
        height = self._do_layout(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, width, 0), True)
        return height

    def setGeometry(self, rect):
        super(FlowLayout, self).setGeometry(rect)
        self._do_layout(rect, False)

    def sizeHint(self):
        return self.minimumSize()

    def minimumSize(self):
        size = QtCore.QSize()

        for item in self._item_list:
            size = size.expandedTo(item.minimumSize())

        size += QtCore.QSize(2 * self.contentsMargins().top(), 2 * self.contentsMargins().top())
        return size

    def _do_layout(self, rect, test_only):
        x = rect.x()
        y = rect.y()
        line_height = 0
        spacing = self.spacing()

        for item in self._item_list:
            style = item.widget().style()
            layout_spacing_x = style.layoutSpacing(
                QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.PushButton, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.PushButton, QtCore.Qt.Horizontal
            )
            layout_spacing_y = style.layoutSpacing(
                QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.PushButton, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.PushButton, QtCore.Qt.Vertical
            )
            space_x = spacing + layout_spacing_x
            space_y = spacing + layout_spacing_y
            next_x = x + item.sizeHint().width() + space_x
            if next_x - space_x > rect.right() and line_height > 0:
                x = rect.x()
                y = y + line_height + space_y
                next_x = x + item.sizeHint().width() + space_x
                line_height = 0

            if not test_only:
                item.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(QtCore.QPoint(x, y), item.sizeHint()))

            x = next_x
            line_height = max(line_height, item.sizeHint().height())

        new_height = y + line_height - rect.y()
        self.heightChanged.emit(new_height)
        return new_height

class WordwrapLabel(QtWidgets.QTextEdit):
    size_change_signal = QtCore.pyqtSignal()
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        # Call the parent constructor
        super(WordwrapLabel, self).__init__(parent)
        self.viewport().setCursor(QtCore.Qt.ArrowCursor)
        self.setStyleSheet('background:transparent;')
        self.selected = False
        self.default_style_sheet = self.styleSheet()
        self.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.NoFrame)
        self.setReadOnly(True)

        self.setTextInteractionFlags(QtCore.Qt.NoTextInteraction)
        self.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
        self.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
    def wheelEvent(self, event):
        event.ignore()
        super(WordwrapLabel, self).wheelEvent(event)
    def resizeEvent(self, event):
        super(WordwrapLabel, self).resizeEvent(event)
        font = self.document().defaultFont()
        font_metrics = QtGui.QFontMetrics(font)
        text_size = font_metrics.size(0, self.toPlainText())
        if text_size.width() >= self.size().width():
            line_factor = int(text_size.width() / self.size().width()) + 1
            new_height = (text_size.height() * line_factor) + 15
            self.setMinimumHeight(new_height)
            self.setMaximumHeight(new_height)
        else:
            height = text_size.height() + 15
            self.setMinimumHeight(height)
            self.setMaximumHeight(height)
class Thumbnail(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None, label=None):
        # Call the parent constructor
        super(Thumbnail, self).__init__(parent)

        self.image_label_width = 0
        self.image_label_height = 0
        self.name_label_min_width = 0
        self.name_label_max_width = 0
        self.name_label_min_height = 18
        self.max_width = 0
        self.max_height = 0
        self.icon_sizes = ['small', 'medium', 'large']
        self.icon_size_index = 1
        self.current_icon_size = 'medium'
        
        self.widget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        master_lyt = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        sub_lyt = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.widget.setLayout(sub_lyt)
        self.image_label = QtWidgets.QLabel()
        image_path = 'D:/PC7/Unzipped/Explosion00-sequence-tga/jpg/explosion00-frame030.jpg'
        self.pic = QtGui.QPixmap()
        self.pic.load(image_path)
        self.image_label.setPixmap(self.pic)
        self.image_label.setScaledContents(True)
        sub_lyt.addWidget(self.image_label, alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)

        name_label = WordwrapLabel()
        if label:
            self.label_text = label
        else:
            self.label_text = 'D:/PC7/Unzipped/Explosion00-sequence-tga/jpg/explosion00-frame030.jpgTestingetlskjfi9023ijd90o8ajsl'
        # label_text = 'explosion00-frame030.jpgl'
        name_label.setHtml(HTML_STRING.format(body=self.label_text))
        sub_lyt.addWidget(name_label, alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)

        master_lyt.addWidget(self.widget)
        self.setLayout(master_lyt)

        self.setIconSize(self.icon_sizes[self.icon_size_index])
    
    def increaseIcon(self):
        self.icon_size_index += 1
        if self.icon_size_index == 3:
            self.icon_size_index = 2
        self.setIconSize(self.icon_sizes[self.icon_size_index])

    def decreaseIcon(self):
        self.icon_size_index -= 1
        if self.icon_size_index == -1:
            self.icon_size_index = 0
        self.setIconSize(self.icon_sizes[self.icon_size_index])

    def setIconSize(self, size):
        if size == 'small':
            self.image_label_width = 25
            self.image_label_height = 25
            self.name_label_min_width = 50
            self.name_label_max_width = 95
            self.max_width = 100
            self.max_height = 100
        elif size == 'medium':
            self.image_label_width = 50
            self.image_label_height = 50
            self.name_label_min_width = 90
            self.name_label_max_width = 145
            self.max_width = 150
            self.max_height = 150
        elif size == 'large':
            self.image_label_width = 80
            self.image_label_height = 80
            self.name_label_min_width = 120
            self.name_label_max_width = 170
            self.max_width = 175
            self.max_height = 175

        self.image_label.setMinimumHeight(self.image_label_width)
        self.image_label.setMinimumWidth(self.image_label_width)
        self.image_label.setMaximumHeight(self.image_label_width)
        self.image_label.setMaximumWidth(self.image_label_width)
        self.widget.setMinimumWidth(self.max_width)
        self.widget.setMaximumWidth(self.max_width)
        self.widget.setMinimumHeight(self.max_height)
        self.widget.setMaximumHeight(self.max_height)

class DialogTest(QtWidgets.QScrollArea):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        # Call the parent constructor
        super(DialogTest, self).__init__(parent)

        # Set the title of the window
        self.setWindowTitle("Icons Test")
        self.selected_icon = None
        # Set the geometry for the window
        self.resize(400, 300)
        
        self.container = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.container_lyt = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()

        filter_horizontal_lyt = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.filter_line_edit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
        filter_horizontal_lyt.addWidget(self.filter_line_edit)
        self.filter_button = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Filter')
        self.filter_button.clicked.connect(self.updateFlowLayout)
        filter_horizontal_lyt.addWidget(self.filter_button)
        self.container_lyt.addLayout(filter_horizontal_lyt)
        horizontal_lyt = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.plus_button = QtWidgets.QPushButton()
        self.plus_button.setText('Plus')
        self.plus_button.clicked.connect(self.increaseIcon)
        horizontal_lyt.addWidget(self.plus_button)
        self.minus_button = QtWidgets.QPushButton()
        self.minus_button.clicked.connect(self.decreaseIcon)
        self.minus_button.setText('Minus')
        horizontal_lyt.addWidget(self.minus_button)
        self.container_lyt.addLayout(horizontal_lyt)
        self.widget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.widget_flow_lyt = FlowLayout()
        self.widget_flow_lyt.heightChanged.connect(self.widget.setMinimumHeight)
        self.widget.setLayout(self.widget_flow_lyt)
        self.button_list = ['passages', 'random', 'years', 'discovered', 'through', 'looks', 'using', 'still', 'roots', 'looking', 'layout', 'generator', 'sentence', 'editors', 'including', 'passage', 'consectetur', 'source', 'going', 'generators', 'suffered', 'remaining', 'specimen', 'reader', 'virginia', 'words', 'during', 'exact', 'ipsum', 'necessary', 'always', 'cicero', 'alteration', 'hampden-sydney', 'popular', 'accompanied', 'obscure', 'aldus', "isn't", 'opposed', 'classical', 'infancy', 'chunk', 'repeat', 'college', 'theory', 'predefined', 'established', 'richard', 'non-characteristic', 'section', 'since', 'sites', 'content', 'written', 'various', 'internet', 'contrary', 'available', 'latin', 'recently', 'reproduced', 'dictionary', 'handful', 'standard', 'release', 'uncover', 'packages', 'generate', 'search', 'accident', 'anything', 'industry', 'reasonable', 'extremes', 'slightly', 'comes', 'first', 'distracted', 'letters', 'humour', 'point', 'galley', 'bonorum', 'simply', 'chunks', 'desktop', 'electronic', 'publishing', 'unknown', 'there', 'readable', 'their', 'combined', 'typesetting', 'sections', 'printer', 'therefore', 'injected', 'essentially', 'rackham', 'survived', 'injected', 'translation', 'repetition', 'industrys', 'hidden', 'those', 'treatise', 'versions', 'default', 'structures', 'variations', 'below', 'printing', 'maloru', 'evolved', 'popularised', 'making', 'distribution', 'piece', 'undoubtable', 'embarrassing', 'unchanged', 'middle', 'believable', 'cites', 'containing', 'more-or-less', 'majority', 'belief', 'interested', 'which', 'literature', 'centuries', 'normal', 'dolor', 'renaissance', 'generated', 'purpose', 'sheets', 'ethics', 'lorem', 'dummy', 'pagemaker', 'randomised', 'professor', 'sometimes', 'letraset', 'looked', 'scrambled', 'english', 'finibus', 'model', 'software', 'original', 'mcclintock']
        self.button_dict = {}
        for btn in self.button_list:
            thumbnail = Thumbnail(self, label=btn)
            self.widget_flow_lyt.addWidget(thumbnail)
            self.button_dict[btn] = thumbnail
        self.container_lyt.addWidget(self.widget)
        self.container_lyt.addStretch()
        self.container.setLayout(self.container_lyt)
        self.setWidgetResizable(True)
        self.setWidget(self.container)

    def resizeEvent(self, event):
        super(DialogTest, self).resizeEvent(event)
        self.container.setMaximumHeight(self.widget.minimumHeight())

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        cursor = event.globalPos()
        if event.button() == QtCore.Qt.LeftButton:
            self.highlightIcon(event, cursor)

    def mouseDoubleClickEvent(self, event):
        pos = self.geometry()
        cursor = event.globalPos()
        if event.button() == QtCore.Qt.LeftButton:
            self.highlightIcon(event, cursor)

    def increaseIcon(self):
        for button_name, button_obj in self.button_dict.items():
            button_obj.increaseIcon()

    def decreaseIcon(self):
        for button_name, button_obj in self.button_dict.items():
            button_obj.decreaseIcon()

    def highlightIcon(self, event, cursor):
            clicked_widget = QtWidgets.QApplication.widgetAt(cursor)
            if clicked_widget == self:
                return                
            thumbnail_widget = self.getThumbnailWidget(clicked_widget)
            if not thumbnail_widget:
                return
            if thumbnail_widget == self.selected_icon and event.modifiers() & QtCore.Qt.ControlModifier:
                self.selected_icon.widget.setStyleSheet('')
                self.selected_icon = None
                return
            if self.selected_icon:
                self.selected_icon.widget.setStyleSheet('')
            thumbnail_widget.widget.setStyleSheet('background-color: cyan;')
            self.selected_icon = thumbnail_widget

    def updateFlowLayout(self):
        for btn_label in self.button_dict:
            filter_key = str(self.filter_line_edit.text())
            if filter_key:
                if filter_key not in btn_label:
                    self.button_dict[btn_label].hide()
            else:
                self.button_dict[btn_label].show()

    def getThumbnailWidget(self, inputWidget):
        if type(inputWidget) == Thumbnail:
            return inputWidget
        parent_widget = inputWidget.parentWidget()
        thumbnail_found = False
        while parent_widget:
            if type(parent_widget) == Thumbnail:
                thumbnail_found = True
                break
            parent_widget = parent_widget.parentWidget()
        if not thumbnail_found:
            parent_widget = None
        return parent_widget

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = DialogTest()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Can anyone give any advice to how to format this better? ideally i want this looking something like this "Content Browser" from Autodesk Maya 2020:
[image]

Also separate question: is there a way to store Qt objects for later use without having them wiped from memory? I have been trying to load maybe 1000 items once and then have them put aside in a dictionary or something while I reset the layout and replace them with something else, but everytime I do that it seems to actually just destroy the pointed C++ object even though that dictionary is still present...

Edit 1: There was as suggestion to try using `QListView.IconMode` in the comments, which looks great but after experimenting I have found this feature is too slow once we start assigning custom thumbnail images and reaches over 50 items.

Comment: Just to note that rather than using something like your `FlowLayout`, you might want to consider [Qt's model/view framework](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/model-view-programming.html) -- perhaps a [`QListView`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlistview.html) using [`QListView::IconMode`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlistview.html#ViewMode-enum).  Have a look at the [puzzle example](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-itemviews-puzzle-example.html)

Comment: As G.M. points out, QListView is exactly what you're looking for. Consider that it is what Qt itself uses for its internal QFileDialog (when not using the native one).  In your specific case, you'll also need a custom delegate.

Comment: ah very interesting, i didnt even know this `IconMode` thing even existed. I will have to play around with that. in the meanwhile is there a solution to this issue with the Flow Layout regardless of how convoluted the implementation is? or is this behaviour just the nature of this Layout...?

Comment: @user3696118 Sorry but we won't go through more than 300 lines of code to tell you what's wrong with it. I can only assume that the layout is using the widget's [`sizeHint()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#sizeHint-prop) to set the geometry whenever its horizontal space allows it, meaning that if there is more space available (which is the case of the second row), the widgets will take it. Setting a proper [sizePolicy](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#sizePolicy-prop) might help, but, as said, using a QListView with `IconMode` is a better choice for this kind of situations.

Comment: sure that is understandable, by the way I realized you also answered to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69474089/how-to-get-item-text-to-wrap-using-a-qlistview-set-to-iconmode-and-model-set-to/69489044#69489044 do you have anymore insight to what you described in this question (specifically the related answer you mentioned)?

Answer (score 0):

after some further experimentation i ended up trying to play with the contents of the Flow Layout itself of to remove or re-add widgets.

[image]

here is the code if anyone is interested in. any feedback for improvements would be greatly appreciated:

```
import sys, re, os
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
PATTERN = re.compile(r'(\d+)(\.)([0-9a-zA-Z]+$)')
HTML_STRING = '<p align=\"center\">{body}</p>'

class FlowLayout(QtWidgets.QLayout):
    heightChanged = QtCore.pyqtSignal(int)
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(FlowLayout, self).__init__(parent)

        if parent is not None:
            self.setContentsMargins(QtCore.QMargins(0, 0, 0, 0))

        self._item_list = []
        self._active_item_list = []

    def __del__(self):
        item = self.takeAt(0)
        while item:
            item = self.takeAt(0)

    def addItem(self, item):
        self._item_list.append(item)

    def count(self):
        return len(self._item_list)

    def itemAt(self, index):
        if 0 <= index < len(self._item_list):
            return self._item_list[index]

        return None

    def takeAt(self, index):
        if 0 <= index < len(self._item_list):
            return self._item_list.pop(index)

        return None

    def expandingDirections(self):
        return QtCore.Qt.Orientation(0)

    def hasHeightForWidth(self):
        return True

    def heightForWidth(self, width):
        height = self._do_layout(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, width, 0), True)
        return height

    def setGeometry(self, rect):
        super(FlowLayout, self).setGeometry(rect)
        self.update()
        self._do_layout(rect, False)

    def sizeHint(self):
        return self.minimumSize()

    def minimumSize(self):
        size = QtCore.QSize()

        for item in self._active_item_list:
            size = size.expandedTo(item.minimumSize())

        size += QtCore.QSize(2 * self.contentsMargins().top(), 2 * self.contentsMargins().top())
        return size

    def _do_layout(self, rect, test_only):
        x = rect.x()
        y = rect.y()
        line_height = 0
        spacing = self.spacing()

        for item in self._item_list:
            style = item.widget().style()
            layout_spacing_x = style.layoutSpacing(
                QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.PushButton, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.PushButton, QtCore.Qt.Horizontal
            )
            layout_spacing_y = style.layoutSpacing(
                QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.PushButton, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.PushButton, QtCore.Qt.Vertical
            )
            space_x = spacing + layout_spacing_x
            space_y = spacing + layout_spacing_y
            next_x = x + item.sizeHint().width() + space_x
            if next_x - space_x > rect.right() and line_height > 0:
                x = rect.x()
                y = y + line_height + space_y
                next_x = x + item.sizeHint().width() + space_x
                line_height = 0
            if not test_only:
                item.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(QtCore.QPoint(x, y), item.sizeHint()))

            x = next_x
            line_height = max(line_height, item.sizeHint().height())

        new_height = y + line_height - rect.y()
        self.heightChanged.emit(new_height)
        return new_height

class WordwrapLabel(QtWidgets.QTextEdit):
    size_change_signal = QtCore.pyqtSignal()
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        # Call the parent constructor
        super(WordwrapLabel, self).__init__(parent)
        self.viewport().setCursor(QtCore.Qt.ArrowCursor)
        self.setStyleSheet('background:transparent;')
        self.selected = False
        self.default_style_sheet = self.styleSheet()
        self.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.NoFrame)
        self.setReadOnly(True)

        self.setTextInteractionFlags(QtCore.Qt.NoTextInteraction)
        self.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
        self.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
    def wheelEvent(self, event):
        event.ignore()
        super(WordwrapLabel, self).wheelEvent(event)
    def resizeEvent(self, event):
        super(WordwrapLabel, self).resizeEvent(event)
        font = self.document().defaultFont()
        font_metrics = QtGui.QFontMetrics(font)
        text_size = font_metrics.size(0, self.toPlainText())
        if text_size.width() >= self.size().width():
            line_factor = int(text_size.width() / self.size().width()) + 1
            new_height = (text_size.height() * line_factor) + 15
            self.setMinimumHeight(new_height)
            self.setMaximumHeight(new_height)
        else:
            height = text_size.height() + 15
            self.setMinimumHeight(height)
            self.setMaximumHeight(height)
class Thumbnail(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None, label=None):
        # Call the parent constructor
        super(Thumbnail, self).__init__(parent)

        self.image_label_width = 0
        self.image_label_height = 0
        self.name_label_min_width = 0
        self.name_label_max_width = 0
        self.name_label_min_height = 18
        self.max_width = 0
        self.max_height = 0
        self.icon_sizes = ['small', 'medium', 'large']
        self.icon_size_index = 1
        self.current_icon_size = 'medium'
        
        self.widget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        master_lyt = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        sub_lyt = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.widget.setLayout(sub_lyt)
        self.image_label = QtWidgets.QLabel()
        image_path = 'D:/PC7/Unzipped/Explosion00-sequence-tga/jpg/explosion00-frame030.jpg'
        self.pic = QtGui.QPixmap()
        self.pic.load(image_path)
        self.image_label.setPixmap(self.pic)
        self.image_label.setScaledContents(True)
        sub_lyt.addWidget(self.image_label, alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)

        name_label = WordwrapLabel()
        if label:
            self.label_text = label
        else:
            self.label_text = 'D:/PC7/Unzipped/Explosion00-sequence-tga/jpg/explosion00-frame030.jpgTestingetlskjfi9023ijd90o8ajsl'
        # label_text = 'explosion00-frame030.jpgl'
        name_label.setHtml(HTML_STRING.format(body=self.label_text))
        sub_lyt.addWidget(name_label, alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)

        master_lyt.addWidget(self.widget)
        self.setLayout(master_lyt)

        self.setIconSize(self.icon_sizes[self.icon_size_index])
    
    def increaseIcon(self):
        self.icon_size_index += 1
        if self.icon_size_index == 3:
            self.icon_size_index = 2
        self.setIconSize(self.icon_sizes[self.icon_size_index])

    def decreaseIcon(self):
        self.icon_size_index -= 1
        if self.icon_size_index == -1:
            self.icon_size_index = 0
        self.setIconSize(self.icon_sizes[self.icon_size_index])

    def setIconSize(self, size):
        if size == 'small':
            self.image_label_width = 25
            self.image_label_height = 25
            self.name_label_min_width = 50
            self.name_label_max_width = 95
            self.max_width = 100
            self.max_height = 100
        elif size == 'medium':
            self.image_label_width = 50
            self.image_label_height = 50
            self.name_label_min_width = 90
            self.name_label_max_width = 145
            self.max_width = 150
            self.max_height = 150
        elif size == 'large':
            self.image_label_width = 80
            self.image_label_height = 80
            self.name_label_min_width = 120
            self.name_label_max_width = 170
            self.max_width = 175
            self.max_height = 175

        self.image_label.setMinimumHeight(self.image_label_width)
        self.image_label.setMinimumWidth(self.image_label_width)
        self.image_label.setMaximumHeight(self.image_label_width)
        self.image_label.setMaximumWidth(self.image_label_width)
        self.widget.setMinimumWidth(self.max_width)
        self.widget.setMaximumWidth(self.max_width)
        self.widget.setMinimumHeight(self.max_height)
        self.widget.setMaximumHeight(self.max_height)

class DialogTest(QtWidgets.QScrollArea):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        # Call the parent constructor
        super(DialogTest, self).__init__(parent)

        # Set the title of the window
        self.setWindowTitle("Icons Test")
        self.selected_icon = None
        # Set the geometry for the window
        self.resize(600, 400)
        
        self.container = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.container_lyt = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()

        filter_horizontal_lyt = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.filter_line_edit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
        filter_horizontal_lyt.addWidget(self.filter_line_edit)
        self.filter_button = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Filter')
        self.filter_button.clicked.connect(self.updateFlowLayout)
        filter_horizontal_lyt.addWidget(self.filter_button)
        self.container_lyt.addLayout(filter_horizontal_lyt)
        horizontal_lyt = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.plus_button = QtWidgets.QPushButton()
        self.plus_button.setText('Plus')
        self.plus_button.clicked.connect(self.increaseIcon)
        horizontal_lyt.addWidget(self.plus_button)
        self.minus_button = QtWidgets.QPushButton()
        self.minus_button.clicked.connect(self.decreaseIcon)
        self.minus_button.setText('Minus')
        horizontal_lyt.addWidget(self.minus_button)
        self.container_lyt.addLayout(horizontal_lyt)
        self.widget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.widget.setSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum)
        self.widget_flow_lyt = FlowLayout()
        self.widget_flow_lyt.heightChanged.connect(self.widget.setMinimumHeight)
        self.widget.setLayout(self.widget_flow_lyt)
        self.button_list = ['passages', 'random', 'years', 'discovered', 'through', 'looks', 'using', 'still', 'roots', 'looking', 'layout', 'generator', 'sentence', 'editors', 'including', 'passage', 'consectetur', 'source', 'going', 'generators', 'suffered', 'remaining', 'specimen', 'reader', 'virginia', 'words', 'during', 'exact', 'ipsum', 'necessary', 'always', 'cicero', 'alteration', 'hampden-sydney', 'popular', 'accompanied', 'obscure', 'aldus', "isn't", 'opposed', 'classical', 'infancy', 'chunk', 'repeat', 'college', 'theory', 'predefined', 'established', 'richard', 'non-characteristic', 'section', 'since', 'sites', 'content', 'written', 'various', 'internet', 'contrary', 'available', 'latin', 'recently', 'reproduced', 'dictionary', 'handful', 'standard', 'release', 'uncover', 'packages', 'generate', 'search', 'accident', 'anything', 'industry', 'reasonable', 'extremes', 'slightly', 'comes', 'first', 'distracted', 'letters', 'humour', 'point', 'galley', 'bonorum', 'simply', 'chunks', 'desktop', 'electronic', 'publishing', 'unknown', 'there', 'readable', 'their', 'combined', 'typesetting', 'sections', 'printer', 'therefore', 'injected', 'essentially', 'rackham', 'survived', 'injected', 'translation', 'repetition', 'industrys', 'hidden', 'those', 'treatise', 'versions', 'default', 'structures', 'variations', 'below', 'printing', 'maloru', 'evolved', 'popularised', 'making', 'distribution', 'piece', 'undoubtable', 'embarrassing', 'unchanged', 'middle', 'believable', 'cites', 'containing', 'more-or-less', 'majority', 'belief', 'interested', 'which', 'literature', 'centuries', 'normal', 'dolor', 'renaissance', 'generated', 'purpose', 'sheets', 'ethics', 'lorem', 'dummy', 'pagemaker', 'randomised', 'professor', 'sometimes', 'letraset', 'looked', 'scrambled', 'english', 'finibus', 'model', 'software', 'original', 'mcclintock']
        self.button_dict = {}
        for btn in self.button_list:
            thumbnail = Thumbnail(self, label=btn)
            self.widget_flow_lyt.addWidget(thumbnail)
            self.button_dict[btn] = thumbnail
        self.container_lyt.addWidget(self.widget)
        self.container_lyt.addStretch()
        self.container.setLayout(self.container_lyt)
        self.setWidgetResizable(True)
        self.setWidget(self.container)

    def resizeEvent(self, event):
        super(DialogTest, self).resizeEvent(event)
        self.container.setMaximumHeight(self.widget.minimumHeight()+50)

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        cursor = event.globalPos()
        if event.button() == QtCore.Qt.LeftButton:
            self.highlightIcon(event, cursor)

    def mouseDoubleClickEvent(self, event):
        pos = self.geometry()
        cursor = event.globalPos()
        if event.button() == QtCore.Qt.LeftButton:
            self.highlightIcon(event, cursor)

    def increaseIcon(self):
        for button_name, button_obj in self.button_dict.items():
            button_obj.increaseIcon()

    def decreaseIcon(self):
        for button_name, button_obj in self.button_dict.items():
            button_obj.decreaseIcon()

    def highlightIcon(self, event, cursor):
            clicked_widget = QtWidgets.QApplication.widgetAt(cursor)
            if clicked_widget == self:
                return                
            thumbnail_widget = self.getThumbnailWidget(clicked_widget)
            if not thumbnail_widget:
                return
            if thumbnail_widget == self.selected_icon and event.modifiers() & QtCore.Qt.ControlModifier:
                self.selected_icon.widget.setStyleSheet('')
                self.selected_icon = None
                return
            if self.selected_icon:
                self.selected_icon.widget.setStyleSheet('')
            thumbnail_widget.widget.setStyleSheet('background-color: cyan;')
            self.selected_icon = thumbnail_widget

    def layout_widgets(self, layout):
        return (layout.itemAt(i) for i in reversed(range(layout.count())))

    def updateFlowLayout(self):
        filter_key = str(self.filter_line_edit.text())
        for btn_label in self.button_dict:
            if self.button_dict[btn_label] not in [x.widget() for x in self.layout_widgets(self.widget_flow_lyt)]:
                self.widget_flow_lyt.addWidget(self.button_dict[btn_label])
                self.button_dict[btn_label].show()
        for item in self.layout_widgets(self.widget_flow_lyt):
            if not item:
                continue
            widget = item.widget()
            if filter_key:
                if filter_key not in widget.label_text:
                    self.widget_flow_lyt.removeItem(item)
                    widget.hide()
        self.resizeEvent(QtGui.QResizeEvent(self.size(), QtCore.QSize()))

    def getThumbnailWidget(self, inputWidget):
        if type(inputWidget) == Thumbnail:
            return inputWidget
        parent_widget = inputWidget.parentWidget()
        thumbnail_found = False
        while parent_widget:
            if type(parent_widget) == Thumbnail:
                thumbnail_found = True
                break
            parent_widget = parent_widget.parentWidget()
        if not thumbnail_found:
            parent_widget = None
        return parent_widget

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = DialogTest()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```