# pyqt QListModelView IconMode highlight to be constant size and add one more line to text?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, qt5

I posted this question below and I was told of a possible alternative `QListModelView.IconMode` which I never heard of before
[Issue with filtering FlowLayout items in PyQt5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74909513/issue-with-filtering-flowlayout-items-in-pyqt5)

I have found this question below to start picking at this Qt feature:
[How to get item text to wrap using a QListView set to IconMode and model set to QFileSystemModel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69474089/how-to-get-item-text-to-wrap-using-a-qlistview-set-to-iconmode-and-model-set-to/)

Something I realized though is if the label size is very short (like two characters) then the selection highlight also gets shrunk to fit that size.

[image]

I am wondering if there is a way to

1. get the selection highlight to always be the same size for every item
2. perhaps not like the above question, but just get the text label to get at least one more line to display...?

here is the current code i have for reference (its basically the same as the code as the above linked question)

```
import sys

from PyQt5 import QtCore
from PyQt5 import QtGui
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets

class TreeViewDialog(QtWidgets.QDialog):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(TreeViewDialog, self).__init__(parent)

        self.setMinimumSize(500, 400)

        self.create_widgets()
        self.create_layout()

    def create_widgets(self):
        root_path = r"C:\Users\PCUser\Documents\pythonFiles"

        self.model = QtWidgets.QFileSystemModel()
        self.model.setRootPath(root_path)

        self.list_view = QtWidgets.QListView()

        self.list_view.setViewMode(QtWidgets.QListView.IconMode)
        self.list_view.setResizeMode(QtWidgets.QListView.Adjust)
        self.list_view.setFlow(QtWidgets.QListView.LeftToRight)
        self.list_view.setMovement(QtWidgets.QListView.Snap)
        self.list_view.setModel(self.model)
        self.list_view.setRootIndex(self.model.index(root_path))
        self.list_view.setGridSize(QtCore.QSize(80, 100))
        self.list_view.setUniformItemSizes(True)
        self.list_view.setWordWrap(True)
        self.list_view.setTextElideMode(QtCore.Qt.ElideRight)

    def create_layout(self):
        main_layout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self)
        main_layout.setContentsMargins(2, 2, 2, 2)
        main_layout.addWidget(self.list_view)

if __name__ == "__main__":

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication.instance()
    if not app:
        app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

    tree_view_dialog = TreeViewDialog()
    tree_view_dialog.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Try removing `self.list_view.setUniformItemSizes(True)`.

Comment: unfortunately that doesnt seem to do much in this instance

Comment: Using your exact code, and commenting that line, I can get icons with multiple lines ([see the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ATUOs.png)). But now I realize that this is also related to the way wrapping is done: even on Windows, if the file has no characters allowing normal wrapping (spaces, hypens, etc.), a long file name will *not* be word wrapped. While Qt allows "wrap anywhere" for some classes and functions, by default Qt views use the standard "wrap at word boundaries".

Comment: yes that is exactly the issue (with a file name containing no normal "separators" like spaces or hyphens). I have been trying to utilize the previous examples but to no luck to produce the behaviour that I described

Comment: I'm afraid that there's no simple or direct solution for that: you need a QListView subclass and a specifically made item delegate that does all you need, including properly done elision (possibly through a QTextLayout).

Comment: i do feel like the answer in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69474089/how-to-get-item-text-to-wrap-using-a-qlistview-set-to-iconmode-and-model-set-to/ hits very close to the desired behaviour but just missing a couple pieces. ideally i would like it so that the icon width is always consistent and the displaying text label to just be a bit longer rather than displaying the entire thing

Answer (score 0):

after messing around i found that the following produces a look I was somewhat looking for, though a lot of the heights/width are hard coded which probably isn't too great but whatever. I put some comments for anyone else wanting to do something similar.

any feedback is greatly appreciated.

[image]

```
import sys

from PyQt5 import QtCore
from PyQt5 import QtGui
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets

class TreeViewDialog(QtWidgets.QDialog):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(TreeViewDialog, self).__init__(parent)

        self.setMinimumSize(500, 400)

        self.create_widgets()
        self.create_layout()

    def create_widgets(self):
        root_path = r"C:\Users\PCUser\Documents\pythonFiles"

        self.model = QtWidgets.QFileSystemModel()
        self.model.setRootPath(root_path)

        self.list_view = QtWidgets.QListView()
        delegate = Highlighter(self)
        self.list_view.setItemDelegate(delegate)

        self.list_view.setViewMode(QtWidgets.QListView.IconMode)
        self.list_view.setResizeMode(QtWidgets.QListView.Adjust)
        self.list_view.setFlow(QtWidgets.QListView.LeftToRight)
        self.list_view.setMovement(QtWidgets.QListView.Snap)
        self.list_view.setModel(self.model)
        self.list_view.setRootIndex(self.model.index(root_path))
        self.list_view.setGridSize(QtCore.QSize(80, 80))
        self.list_view.setWordWrap(True)

    def create_layout(self):
        main_layout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self)
        main_layout.setContentsMargins(2, 2, 2, 2)
        main_layout.addWidget(self.list_view)

class Highlighter(QtWidgets.QStyledItemDelegate):

    def paint(self, painter, opts, index):
        if not index.isValid():
            return

        painter.save()
        
        # Selected
        if opts.state & QtWidgets.QStyle.State_MouseOver:
            painter.fillRect(opts.rect, QtGui.QColor(0,125,125,20))
        if opts.state & QtWidgets.QStyle.State_Selected:
            painter.fillRect(opts.rect, QtGui.QColor(0,125,255,60))
        mode = QtGui.QIcon.Normal
        state = QtGui.QIcon.On if opts.state & QtWidgets.QStyle.State_Open else QtGui.QIcon.Off
        icon = index.data(QtCore.Qt.DecorationRole)
        icon_rect = opts.rect.adjusted(0, 6, 0, 0) # this is for the padding/margins of the icon, though it seems like only the second number is more relevant
        icon_rect.setSize(QtCore.QSize(opts.rect.width(), 35)) # this sets the icon size, realistically the second number is the only thing that matters. depending on your screen resolution, OS, or whatever this 35 value may not work
        icon.paint(painter,icon_rect, alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter | QtCore.Qt.AlignVCenter, mode=mode, state=state)
        text = index.data(QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole)
        rect = opts.rect.adjusted(4, 45, -12, -4) # mess around with the padding/margins for how the text is aligned
        painter.drawText(rect, QtCore.Qt.AlignHCenter | QtCore.Qt.AlignTop | QtCore.Qt.TextWrapAnywhere, opts.fontMetrics.elidedText(text, QtCore.Qt.ElideRight, opts.rect.width()*1.5)) # i added this *1.5 thing to allow for more characters to pop up
        painter.restore()

    def sizeHint(self, option, index):
        if not index.isValid():
            return super(Highlighter, self).sizeHint(option, index)
        else:
            text = index.data(QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole)
            font = QtWidgets.QApplication.font()
            font_metrics = QtGui.QFontMetrics(font)
            rect = font_metrics.boundingRect(0, 0, option.rect.width(), 0,
                                         QtCore.Qt.AlignLeft | QtCore.Qt.AlignTop | QtCore.Qt.TextWrapAnywhere,
                                         text)
            size = QtCore.QSize(option.rect.width(), 65+rect.height()) # try adjusting this 65 value for the height of the "bounding box" thing of the text
            return size


if __name__ == "__main__":

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication.instance()
    if not app:
        app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

    tree_view_dialog = TreeViewDialog()
    tree_view_dialog.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```